# Differences in linking behavior between Ubuntu and CentOS

Tags: c, ubuntu, linker, centos

I'm building two shared libraries, with one library (B) dependent on the other (A) and both being built with an `rpath` of `$ORIGIN/.`, then link an executable to library B. So the dependencies are as follows:

executable C -> library B -> library A

On Ubuntu, B's dependency on A is resolved using its `rpath`, while on CentOS the linker warns that A could not be found and I should use "try using `-rpath` or `-rpath-link`" during the compilation of the executable.

Here's a minimal example to reproduce the issue:

```
mkdir testdir
echo 'void a() {}' > testdir/a.c
echo 'int a(); void b() { a(); }' > testdir/b.c
echo 'int b(); int main() { b(); }' > testdir/c.c
gcc testdir/a.c -shared -o testdir/liba.so -Wl,-rpath,'$ORIGIN/.' -fPIC
gcc testdir/b.c -Ltestdir -la -shared -o testdir/libb.so -Wl,-rpath,'$ORIGIN/.' -fPIC
gcc testdir/c.c -Ltestdir -lb -o testdir/a.out
```

What difference between linking behavior on Ubuntu and CentOS is causing this issue? Is there a way that I can "fix" this, so that A will be resolved without having to rely on things like `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`?

---

**Update:** If I use the absolute path to the library directory instead of `$ORIGIN`, this seems to work. Of course I don't know the absolute path to where they will be deployed, so this doesn't solve this issue, but it points to `$ORIGIN` not being supported by CentOS 7 (or its loader).

Comment: what happens if you add `-la` to the last command? or just `testdir/liba.so`?

Comment: It will work then, same if I set the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. If it is possible on CentOS (or other RedHat based distros) to hint to a dependency's runtime location using `rpath` I would strongly prefer that, however, as it would mean that users of the library will not be required to list all dependencies which are already listed as part of the library.

Comment: you can use -rpath with ORIGIN in the last link as well.

Comment: Which versions of CentOS and Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: @rici CentOS 7 and Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: @Serge adding `-Wl,-rpath,'$ORIGIN/.'` to the last command does not change the outcome, only linking the library explicitly or setting the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` has worked so far there. I'm trying to understand why the `$ORIGIN` `rpath` mechanism doesn't seem to work on CentOS.

Comment: @florian: does adding `-Wl,--enable-new-dtags` help? (On the liba.so and libb.so builds)?

Comment: @rici It did not help, but it has changed the libraries insofar that the `runpath` instead of the `rpath` is being set.

Comment: @florian: could it be [this bug](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=20535)? That is marked as having been fixed in bunutils 2.28, which I think is between the versions on your systems.

Comment: @rici CentOS 7 has binutils 2.27, so you're probably right. At least I know what's the issue then. Thanks! Please post it as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem here could be [this bug](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=20535), reported against binutils 2.26 but presumably present in earlier versions as well. The issue is that the linker `ld`, unlike the dynamic loader `ld.so`, did not interpret the special replacement string `$ORIGIN` in the rpath, so only an absolute path could be used.

The bug was marked as fixed in binutils 2.28, but Centos 7 has binutils 2.27. Ubuntu 18.4, on the other hand, uses binutils 2.30.